# Checking if user owns child records (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I am having a quite big problem with the following queries. The tables looks like:

## A (Parent)

```
+------------+---------+
| id | user_id | value |
+------------+---------+
|  1 |     20 |      X |
|  2 |     20 |      Y |
|  3 |     12 |      Z |
+------------+---------+
```

## B (Child)

```
+------------+-----------+
| id | parent_id | value |
+------------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |     X |
|  2 |         2 |     Y |
|  3 |         2 |     Z |
+------------+-----------+
```

## C (Childs of the Child records)

```
+------------+-----------+
| id | parent_id | value |
+------------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |     X |
|  2 |         1 |     Y |
|  3 |         1 |     Z |
+------------+-----------+
```

I need two (separate) queries. The first for verification if records in the table B belongs to the user id = X and then if records in the table C belongs to the user id = X. So for example I have got IDs (1, 2, 3, 18, 329) of records from the table C and I need to check if these values belong to the user id = 20. The result should be 1, 2, 3. How can I do this? I don't work with SQL a lot so I am completely lost and I appreciate every help. Thanks

Comment: Are these the real names of the tables and columns? Obfuscating them does not help anyone.

Comment: The columns names are real ,but the tables are not. If I change the tables names it will get just worse if you don't know the project that I am working on. It is basically parent, child structure.

Comment: If there are foreign keys defined, add the `CREATE TABLE` code for the tables.

Comment: No there are not any foreign keys defined.

Comment: I haven't defined any foreign keys. I guess I should.

Comment: Yes, you are right the B (parent_id) references the A (id) and the C (parent_id) references the B(id). The value is not really important in this case it is just value that belongs to the specific record. It can be whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Select` with 2 joins:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM c
  INNER JOIN b ON b.id = c.parent_id
  INNER JOIN a ON a.id = b.parent_id
WHERE c.id in (1, 2, 3, 18, 329)
  AND a.user_id = 20 ;
```

Comment: Select c.id .. with .. WHERE c.id IN?

Comment: Yes, `c.value` should be `c.id` and also is missing user_id (I want to select only records that belongs to the specific user). Have a look at this: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b44c3/1/0) is it right to use it like this?

Comment: See my update please!

Comment: Please don't compare apples to oranges, i.e: don't compare strings (`'20'`) to numbers (`20`). If `user_id` is defined as an integer column use a proper number: `20`

Comment: I made a typing mistake in the sqlfiddle example. Is it better to use just `user_id` or `a.user_id`?

Comment: As long as the column is unique, it makes no differences

Comment: Thanks, by the way the IDs in (...) are integers as well ;)